# How do I add a unique key to a column in MYSQL?

Tags: mysql, database

If I want one column to be unique, or two, or three?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
ALTER TABLE xx ADD UNIQUE KEY keyname (column1,column2);
```

Answer (score 0):

You want to apply a [unique constriaint](http://www.w3schools.com/SQl/sql_unique.asp):

> The UNIQUE constraint uniquely identifies each record in a database table.